# Как увеличить border, не сломав перемещение объекта

Tags: javascript, php, html

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>drag und drop save</title>







<style type="text/css">
        body {
        border: 1px black solid;
            padding:0;
            margin:200;
            overflow:hidden;


            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }
        #menue { 
            position: absolute;
            left: 30vw;
            top: 20vh;
        }



    </style>


</head>
<body id="droppable">

<div id="menue">
 <button id="rese">remove storage planeposition</button>  
<div id="text"></div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
</div>

<div 
class="dragme">
<img id="draggable" class="plane" src="http://img.time2draw.com/2014/06/Vehicles-Plane-step-by-final-step-215x382.png" border="0" alt=""/>
</div>



  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js'></script>



    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

java script

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
       $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
x=$('.plane').position();
        x1=x.left;
        y1=x.top;
 localStorage.setItem('leftplane',x1);
 localStorage.setItem('topplane',y1);       

      }
    });
 $('.plane').css('top',localStorage.getItem('topplane')+'px');
$('.plane').css('left',localStorage.getItem('leftplane')+'px');
$('#rese').click(function(){
  localStorage.removeItem('leftplane');
  localStorage.removeItem('topplane');
   $('.plane').css('top','0px');
     $('.plane').css('left','0px');               
});
```

Comment: Приведите код в порядок, у вас почему-то два тега `head` и `html` в `html`

Comment: и не понятно что не так